# Corruption When Downloading IMAP File Attachments in Python 2.7

Tags: python, imap, email-attachments

I'm downloading file attachments from an IMAP email. Code as follows:

```
header = '(' +  'SUBJECT '+ '"' +'A SPECIFIED MESSAGE HEADER'"' + ')'

# Connect to an IMAP server
def connect(server, user, password):
    m = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(server)
    m.login(user, password)
    m.select()
    return m

# Download all attached files 

def downloadAttachmentsInEmail(m, emailid, outputdir):
    resp, data = m.fetch(emailid, "(BODY.PEEK[])")
    email_body = data[0][1]
    mail = email.message_from_string(email_body)

    # check for attachment;
    for part in mail.walk():
        if not mail.is_multipart():
            continue
        if mail.get('Content-Disposition'):
            continue
        file_name = part.get_filename()

        if file_name:
            file = open(outputdir + '/' + file_name,'w+')
            file.write(part.get_payload(decode=True))
            file.close()

m = connect(<IMAP SERVER>,<EMAIL ACCOUNT>,<PASSWORD>)

m.select('INBOX', readonly=True)
typ, emailid = m.search(None, header)
downloadAttachmentsInEmail(m, emailid[0], outputdir)
```

The code works fine. When I check the output directory after downloading everything looks good.  But when I try to open the files (excel files and pdfs) I am unable to and I get a corruption error.

Suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this on Windows? Does `open(outputdir + '/' + file_name, 'wb+')` change anything? And please, don't call your files `file`.

Comment: Fixed it!!  What does `wb+` do that `w+` doesn't?  Is it just bad form to call files file?

Comment: `wb+`  opens the file in binary mode. Normal open uses text mode, where [line endings maybe rewritten](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open). When you assign `file` as a variable, you overwrite the builtin [`file`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#file), which, yes, is bad style. But since using `file()` is deprecated in favor of `open()` ...